# Host ASP.NET Core MVC app with multiple pathbase in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to host an ASP.NET Core MVC web app with different paths?

For example: I've an ASP.NET Core MVC web app hosted in IIS, with binding `test.com`.

Is it possible to cover multiple paths (app1, app2) without having to create multiple application under test.com.

```
https://test.com/app1/home
https://test.com/app2/home
```

Comment: The question is not possible or not (everything is possible), but what do you want to display for such URLs exactly?

Comment: I want to display the same page but with few changes. For example: different logos based on the path

Comment: The virtual directory should meet your requirements: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory).

Comment: Thanks @samwu , is there any other way without creating these virtual directories?

Comment: Your desire to use the same IIS application to serve different user groups (like companies) has been proven by the industry to be poor design in many ways. Proper isolation among user groups is very important for a SaaS product, so container technologies are widely used. Even if you only have a single IIS server, you should use separate IIS applications to isolate the resources.

Comment: @KannanM Virtual directory is the most convenient way, as far as I know, there is no other way in iis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was achieved using UsePathBase (instead of creating multiple applications under IIS)

In StartUp.cs, added the below code to achieve it. WebsitePaths is a list of string ("app1", "app2").

```
foreach (var path in WebsitePaths)
{
   app.UsePathBase(new PathString($"/{path}"));
}
```

Note: I have the same user group who can access multiple site under multiple paths (app1,app2 - to display different contents) under a single domain (test.com).